# Building OS X Native App With FireBase Template and Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase

I am trying to build a native OS X app with the new Firebase Templates:

[Firebase Gitub](https://github.com/firebase)

I am encountering linker errors, that make me think the definition of the class FServerValues is missing:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FServerValues", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Firebase(FRepo.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Has anyone else tried to build a simple project using the Firebase Templates in Xcode 4.6.3? If so did you get these errors? Were you able to fix them?

Comment: Oops, looks like an error in our latest release. I'll get that fixed ASAP and update the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed now. Please replace your copy of Firebase.framework with the latest one, available here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html

Apologies for the oversight, and please let me know if you run in to any more trouble.

Comment: Great! Thanks for such a super quick response. The templates build correctly now.

Comment: This is still not working with Firebase 2.4.0 Verison
I am getting the same errors.